# Tilde over Hebrew letter

Tags: symbols, glossaries, characters, hebrew, tilde

I need a simple solution for making a tilde over a Hebrew sign.
`\tilde{א}` doesn't work. I also tried it with `\makebox` and `\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}` but `\makebox` produces more other mistakes. 
Are there any other ideas what I can do?

I am using the character in glossaries: `\newglossaryentry{שה}{name={\ensuremath{\tilde{שה}}},description={Blabla}}`

Example:
(I'm compiling using xelatex with arara)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{EzraSIL} %Keter YG

\usepackage[xindy={language=hebrew,glsnumbers=false},counter=pageline,nosuper,nolong]{glossaries}

\glsSetCompositor{-}% Use - as separator
\pretocmd{\gls}{\doedindexlabel}{}{}% Call \doedindexlabel at the begining of \gls

\makeglossaries

\newglossarystyle{germanhebrew}
{% base it on the tree style:
  \setglossarystyle{tree}%
  % switch to german
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}%
     \begin{german}
    }%
    {\end{german}}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \hangindent0pt\relax
    \parindent0pt\relax
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{%
      \texthebrew{\glossentryname{##1}}}}%
    \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
    \glstreepredesc\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2\par
  }%
}


\newglossaryentry{שה}{name={\ensuremath{\tilde{שה}}},description={Abkürzung}}


\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
%\setotherlanguage{arabic}

%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.3]{Scheherazade}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}

Bla Bla Bla \gls{שה} 

\printglossary[style=germanhebrew]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should make a small, complete example and say how you are compiling (xelatex, pdflatex?).

Comment: I've add an example above

Comment: That's a snippet not a complete example. Do you expect me to spent my time to extend it to real test document?

Comment: Now we have a complete example and you could try to tackle the "small" part of "small,complete example".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the hebrew in a \mbox and then use \widetilde. Be aware that different fonts are used for hebrew if you use or don't use \texthebrew:

```
\documentclass{article} %to get everything on one page
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[xindy={language=hebrew,glsnumbers=false},nosuper,nolong]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{EzraSIL} %Keter YG

\newglossaryentry{whatever} {name={\ensuremath{\widetilde{\mbox{\texthebrew{הש}}}}},description={Abkürzung}}
\newglossaryentry{something}{name={\ensuremath{\widetilde{\mbox{שה}}}},description={Abkürzung}}
\begin{document}


Bla Bla Bla \gls{something}

Bla Bla Bla \gls{whatever}

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks very much! that works perfectly fine – but why? what is the difference between \makebox and \mbox?

Comment: \makebox is fragile (it has an optional argument). \protect\makebox works probably too, but \mbox is shorter anyway.